# Python Bokeh contents on graph not changed when the value of Select is changed

Tags: python, select, drop-down-menu, bokeh

Hi this is my first question on stack overflow so if there's any problem with my question apologies first.

I'm new to Python Bokeh and trying to make an interactive graph with a dropdown list using Select, here's my code:

```
import random as rd
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.layouts import layout, widgetbox
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, HoverTool, Div
from bokeh.models.widgets import Select
from bokeh.io import show, output_file, curdoc
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file

low = 1
high = 400
mylistX1 = [(rd.randint(low, high)) for k in range(100)]
mylistY1 = [(rd.randint(low, high)) for k in range(100)]
mylistX2 = [(rd.randint(low, high)) for k in range(100)]
mylistY2 = [(rd.randint(low, high)) for k in range(100)]

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=[], y=[]))


def update():
    group_val = select.value
    if group_val == "both":
        source.data = dict(x=mylistX1+mylistX2, y=mylistY1+mylistY2)
    elif group_val == "one":
        source.data = dict(x=mylistX1, y=mylistY1)
    elif group_val == "two":
        source.data = dict(x=mylistX2, y=mylistY2)


p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)

p.circle(source=source, x='x', y='y', size=10, alpha=0.5, color='navy')

select = Select(title='Group', options=["both", "one", "two"], value="both")

select.on_change('value', lambda attr, old, new: update())
sizing_mode = 'fixed'

inputs = widgetbox(select, sizing_mode=sizing_mode)
l = layout([
    [inputs, p]
], sizing_mode=sizing_mode)

update()

curdoc().add_root(l)
curdoc().title = "GG"

show(l)
```

So basically I have set the value of the Select box to "both" and when I change the value of it the corresponding graph will be changed as well. Now the problem is, the graph is not updated when I change the value in the dropdown list: it always shows me the graph of "both", and interestingly when I change the initial value to "one" or "two" the graph shows me only the graph of "one" or "two". So it seems that my "select.on_change" command is not working at all becasue the value of "select" seems to be fixed. What is the problem with that command?

btw I'm using python 2.7 and the bokeh version is 0.12.10 and preferably I don't want to use Javascript solution, which I have seen in other places.

update: I just tried to run it in my localhost and it works but when I try to open it with my browser(safari) the problem remains. Why is that? I'm working on a group project so maybe localhost is not enough...

Thank you very much